# Selecting same column twice

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to also select value from xcart_extra_field_values WHERE fieldid = 5. From looking around, it seems what I need to do is use a join and aliases, however I can't seem to figure out how to join the table on itself, and just using another alias for value, and trying to pull in the same table twice crashed my database. Twice.

This my current query, which works:

```
                            SELECT a.avail,
                                c.value,
                                b.productid,
                                a.productcode,
                         FROM xcart_products a,
                              xcart_products_lng_en b,
                              xcart_extra_field_values c,
                         WHERE a.productid IN
                             (SELECT productid
                              FROM xcart_extra_field_values
                              WHERE a.productid = productid
                                AND fieldid = 5
                                AND (LOWER(value) = 'retail'
                                     OR LOWER(value) = 'stock'
                                     OR LOWER(value) = 'c1 stock'
                                     OR LOWER(value) = 'c2 stock'
                                     OR LOWER(value) = 'g stock') )
                           AND c.fieldid = 9
                           AND (a.productid = b.productid)
                           AND (b.productid = c.productid)
```

This is the query that crashes the database:

```
                            SELECT a.avail,
                                c.value,
                                d.value,
                                b.productid,
                                a.productcode
                         FROM xcart_products a,
                              xcart_products_lng_en b,
                              xcart_extra_field_values c,
                              xcart_extra_field_values d
                         WHERE a.productid IN
                             (SELECT productid
                              FROM xcart_extra_field_values
                              WHERE a.productid = productid
                                AND fieldid = 5
                                AND (LOWER(value) = 'retail'
                                     OR LOWER(value) = 'stock'
                                     OR LOWER(value) = 'c1 stock'
                                     OR LOWER(value) = 'c2 stock'
                                     OR LOWER(value) = 'g stock') )
                           AND c.fieldid = 9
                           AND d.fieldid = 5
                           AND (a.productid = b.productid)
                           AND (b.productid = c.productid)
```

Comment: THis is not clear,is that query working or is it your attempt?

Comment: Is your use of LOWER() strictly necessary? It'll render any index on value useless and probably slow down you query. Unless they are binarys strings `=` is case-insensitive anyway.

Comment: @Mihai; I've made the question more clear by including the code that works alongside the code that doesn't
@Arth; Yes. Employees manually enter in the stock locations, and so it may be G stock, Retail, Stock, STOCK, RETAIL, etc.

Comment: You missed the part where I said `=` is case-insensitive unless they are BINARY strings. VARCHARs are ok.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd write it:

```
 SELECT xp.avail,
        xpe5.value,
        xpe9.value,
        xpl.productid,
        xp.productcode
   FROM xcart_products xp
   JOIN xcart_products_lng_en xpl
     ON xpl.productid = xp.productid
   JOIN xcart_extra_field_values xpe5
     ON xpe5.productid = xp.productid
    AND xpe5.fieldid = 5
    AND xpe5.value IN ('retail','stock','c1 stock','c2 stock','g stock')
   JOIN xcart_extra_field_values xpe9
     ON xpe9.productid = xp.productid
    AND xpe9.fieldid = 9
```

Assuming you have all other indexes in place, your `xpe5` value check is probably what's letting the side down.

I would never let the employee input a fixed stock location into the database from a textbox.. you should have a dropdown with a set of values at the very least (maybe let the employee add values for new stock locations). I'd probably put the stock location options in a separate table and put in a foreign key to that in the main table.

Comment: Well, it works, and it's a little faster than my own query, but I'm not sure if that's because you removed the LOWER functions.

The query is a lot smaller, but it's obfuscated quite a bit by having four different aliases. But it works, so I'll mark this as useful.

Comment: @MartynShutt Happy to help.. but obfuscated?! I used the table names, as opposed to a,b,c,d. I have also used explicit JOINs to group all the conditions nicely as opposed to implicit JOINs, which the majority of the community has moved on from as they are hard to read and prone to user-error (no dig at you).

Comment: I just meant your naming conventions, xp, xpl, xpe5, xpe9. I guess I don't really need to worry about what they're called. It just looked a bit odd to me. As I said my knowledge of MySQL is limited, and I know I'm using outdated practices, but I'm trying to get a project finished, and so whatever works right now, will do the job until my MySQL improves.

Comment: @MartynShutt Well alias conventions are up to you of course, but I tend to use the initials of a table or something similar (like xpe for 'xcart products extra' instead of xcart_extra_field_values), and if a table is used twice (xcart_extra_field_values in this case) I add a qualifier (5 or 9 in for the field ids). From experience, I'd stay away from a,b,c,d as that can be a mind melt in larger queries and writing out a full table name for each column can be tiresome :). Good luck with it all!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working now. Typical when I post mysql questions.

```
                            SELECT a.avail,
                                    c.value,
                                    d.value,
                                    b.productid,
                                    a.productcode
                             FROM xcart_products a,
                                  xcart_products_lng_en b,
                                  xcart_extra_field_values c,
                                  xcart_extra_field_values d
                             WHERE a.productid IN
                                 (SELECT productid
                                  FROM xcart_extra_field_values
                                  WHERE a.productid = productid
                                    AND fieldid = 5
                                    AND (LOWER(value) = 'retail'
                                         OR LOWER(value) = 'stock'
                                         OR LOWER(value) = 'c1 stock'
                                         OR LOWER(value) = 'c2 stock'
                                         OR LOWER(value) = 'g stock') )
                               AND c.fieldid = 9
                               AND d.fieldid = 5
                               AND (a.productid = b.productid)
                               AND (b.productid = c.productid)
                               AND (c.productid = d.productid)
```

I need to also compare c.productid to d.productid. However, I'm not pleased with my own answer, as it seems terribly inefficient. This is, unfortunately, due to my own limited understanding of mysql.